# Comment a single node

Tags: xslt

Using XSLT, how can I comment a single node without commenting its children?

I have this html:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="blah" style="blahblah">
      <span>
        <p>test</p>
      </span>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I would like this output:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <!-- div class="blah" style="blahblah" -->
      <span>
        <p>test</p>
      </span>
    <!-- /div -->
  </body>
</html>
```

It is key that the children nodes are copied and any attributes of the commented node are also copied.

The following is my best try but doesn't work. XSLT processor yells out: 
"Attribute and namespace nodes cannot be added to the parent element after a text, comment, pi, or sub-element node has already been added."

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <!-- IdentityTransform -->
    <xsl:template match="/ | @* | node()">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="div">
      <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;!--</xsl:text>
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">--&gt;</xsl:text>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;!--</xsl:text>
      </xsl:copy>
      <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">--&gt;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a pretty ghastly use of XSLT, but this appears to work, and I can't think of a cleaner approach:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <!-- IdentityTransform -->
  <xsl:template match="/ | @* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="div">
    <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;!--</xsl:text>
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
      <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">--&gt;</xsl:text>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
      <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;!--</xsl:text>
    </xsl:copy>
    <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">--&gt;</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I can't imagine why you wouldn't use `<xsl:comment>`.

Comment: Accepting this answer because it is shorter than Lego's and seems simpler.

Comment: @torazaburo I tried it but could not get it to work.  Also, wouldn't it create bad nesting?

Comment: @torazaburo I didn't use `<:xsl:comment>` because that would require manually constructing the tags and attributes instead of letting the XSLT processor do it.

Comment: @JLRishe You are manually creating the tags for the comment already.

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr I'm obviously aware of that, but I think that's preferable to manually constructing the element tags _and_ the attributes. Also, your approach will create improperly nested quotes if any of the attributes contains `&quot;`.

Answer (score 1):

Its worth pointing out you can just use `<xsl:comment>` to create comments in the output XML without having to worry about closing them correctly. What you've done could easily cause problems down the line if the closing comment delimiter wasn't put in correctly.

This will do the trick:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <!-- IdentityTransform -->
    <xsl:template match="/ | @* | node()">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="div">
      <xsl:comment>
          <xsl:text> div </xsl:text>
          <xsl:for-each select="@*">
               <xsl:value-of select="local-name()"/>
               <xsl:text>="</xsl:text>
               <xsl:value-of select="."/>
               <xsl:text>" </xsl:text>
           </xsl:for-each>
      </xsl:comment>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="./*" />
      <xsl:comment> /div </xsl:comment>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And when the output is pretty-printed, it gives this:

```
<html>
   <body>
      <!-- div class="blah" style="blahblah" -->
      <span>
         <p>test</p>
      </span>
      <!-- /div -->
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you Lego! I wish I could choose more than one answer as yours seems to provide a more standard way of doing this given its use of <xsl:comment>